# Python: How expensive is to create a small list many times?

Tags: python

I encounter the following small annoying dilemma over and over again in Python:

Option 1:

cleaner but slower(?) if called many times since a_list get re-created for each call of do_something()

```
def do_something():    
  a_list = ["any", "think", "whatever"]    
  # read something from a_list
```

Option 2:

Uglier but more efficient (spare the a_list creation all over again)

```
a_list = ["any", "think", "whatever"]    
def do_something():    
  # read something from a_list
```

What do you think?

Comment: when in doubt, go for the most readable, elegant, self-documenting code you can until a performance profiler tells you not to.

Comment: Yes I know. But this is such a small and annoying and easy to avoid thing...

Comment: "small" means ignore it.  Do what ever is most clear.  Leave performance considerations aside until you can *prove* it's a problem.

Comment: As per my answer, use classes. Data+method is what they are for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What's ugly about it?

Are the contents of the list always constants, as in your example? If so: recent versions of Python (since 2.4) will optimise that by evaluating the constant expression and keeping the result but only if it's a tuple. So you could change it to being a tuple. Or you could stop worrying about small things like that.

Here's a list of constants and a tuple of constants:

```
>>> def afunc():
...    a = ['foo', 'bar', 'zot']
...    b = ('oof', 'rab', 'toz')
...    return
...
>>> import dis; dis.dis(afunc)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bar')
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('zot')
              9 BUILD_LIST               3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          15 LOAD_CONST               7 (('oof', 'rab', 'toz'))
             18 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4          21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. That tuples get optimized to be created only once. Interesting.. This would probably solve 90% of the cases of the OP

Comment: @AnonymousDriveByDownVoter: care to leave a comment?

Answer (score 4):

Never create something more than once if you don't have to.  This is a simply optimization that can be done on your part and I personally do not find the second example ugly at all.

Some may argue not to worry about optimizing little things like this but I feel that something this simple to fix should be done immediately.  I would hate to see your application create multiple copies of anything that it doesn't need to simply to preserve an arbitrary sense of "code beauty". :)

Answer (score 4):

Option 3:

```
def do_something(a_list = ("any", "think", "whatever")):
    read something from a_list
```

**Option 3 compared to Option 1:**

Both are equally readable in my opinion (though some seem to think differently in the comments! :-) ). You could even write Option 3 like this

```
def do_something(
    a_list = ("any", "think", "whatever")):
    read something from a_list
```

which really minimizes the difference in terms of readability. 
Unlike Option 1, however, Option 3 defines `a_list` only once -- at the time when `do_something` is defined. That's exactly what we want.

**Option 3 compared to Option 2:**

Avoid global variables if possible. Option 3 allows you to do that.
Also, with Option 2, over time or if other people maintain this code, the definition of `a_list` could get separated from `def do_something`. This may not be a big deal, but I think it is somewhat undesireable.

Comment: Gneee... Sorry, seeing a list as a default parameter hurts.

Comment: -1 "Avoid global variables when you can" is sound advice, but "Python is force[d] to first search for the variable in the locals() dict" is utter codswallop. The COMPILER knows whether it is local or global, and in the option 2 case emits a LOAD GLOBAL instruction. The locals() dict is manifested when and only when you call the locals() function -- the COMPILER knows where all the locals are stored; no dict is used for running normal function/method code.

Answer (score 3):

if your `a_list` doesn't change, move it out of the function.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have some data
2. You have a method associated with it
3. You don't want to keep the data globally just for the sake of optimising the speed of the method unless you have to.

I think this is what classes are for.

```
class Processor:
    def __init__(this):
        this.data = "any thing whatever".split()
    def fun(this,arg):
        # do stuff with arg and list

inst = Processor()
inst.fun("skippy)
```

Also, if you someday want to separate out the data into a file, you can just modify the constructor to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems it comes down to initializing the array in the function or not:

```
import time
def fun1():
        a = ['any', 'think', 'whatever']
        sum = 0
        for i in range(100):
                sum += i

def fun2():
        sum = 0
        for i in range(100):
                sum += i


def test_fun(fun, times):
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(times):
                fun()
        end=time.time()
        print "Function took %s" % (end-start)

# Test
print 'warming up'
test_fun(fun1, 100)
test_fun(fun2, 100)

print 'Testing fun1'
test_fun(fun1, 100000)
print 'Testing fun2'
test_fun(fun2, 100000)

print 'Again'
print 'Testing fun1'
test_fun(fun1, 100000)
print 'Testing fun2'
test_fun(fun2, 100000)
```

and the results:

```
>python test.py
warming up
Function took 0.000604152679443
Function took 0.000600814819336
Testing fun1
Function took 0.597407817841
Testing fun2
Function took 0.580779075623
Again
Testing fun1
Function took 0.595198154449
Testing fun2
Function took 0.580571889877
```

Looks like there is no difference.

Comment: It might help if you called do_fun1() somewhere. ;-)

Comment: Nesting it inside a function is something else altogether. Try it under the conditions that we're discussing: (1) local (2) global (3) default arg (4) local but as a tuple instead of a list. Also alarge part of the time is spent on the for loop which is all irrelevant. Throw away the loop, and throw in an option (0) no list/tuple at all then report (1)-(0), (2)-(0) etc

Answer (score 0):

If the list is never modified, why do you use lists at all?

Without knowing your actual requirements, I'd recommend to simply use some if-statements to get rid of the list and the "read something from list" part completely.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on automated systems that process 100,000,000+ records a day, where a 1% percent performance improvement is huge.

I learned a big lesson working on that system:  Faster is better, but only when you know when it's fast enough.

A 1% improvement would have been a huge reduction in total processing time, but it isn't enough to effect when we would need our next hardware upgrade.  My application was so fast, that the amount of time I spent trying to milk that last 1% probably cost more than a new server would have.

In your case, you would have to call do_something tens of thousands of times before making a significant difference in performance.  In some cases that would make a difference, in other it won't.